# string split on multiple delimeters

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, string, pandas

I have a dataset in which a column **info** consists of strings like this:

```
data['info'][0] = 'Banshidhar Roadlines - Ahmedabad Address Opp. Mahadev Avenue, Nr. Sardar Patel Ring Road, Ahmedabad Email : WebSite : City : Ahmedabad, Ahmedabad Pin Code : 382415 State : Gujarat, India Contact No. : 079- - 29292559, 65447413, GST No. : Company Registration No. : About Company Contact Person : Santram B. Yadav Mobile No. : 9376102361, 9377177197, Contact Person : Mobile No. : , , Contact Person : Mobile No. : , , Truck Available : Services : Daily Service :-Gujarat, Maharashtra, Karnataka, Rajasthan, U.P., Bihar & All Over India '
```

I want to split the string such that I can get data like Email, Website, City, Pin code, etc., each in its own column. I tried using `re.split` but there are multiple values of **Contact Person** in the string.

How do I differentiate between them?

Comment: How do you *want* to differentiate between them?

Comment: Create a different column for each "Contact Person" like Contact_Person_1,Contact_Person_2...

Comment: In your example therer are three contact person slots, of which two are empty. Is there always three "positions" for contact person in the data?

Comment: Yes there is always three positions for contact person, some of which may or may not contain the data

Comment: This question is WAY too broad, especially considering you have only provided one line of data, you cannot reasonably expect any answer given here to work for all 100,000 rows (or however many you have, >> 1 surely).

Comment: Well I have 13,500 rows, all in the same format and if the code works for 1 row then it would work for every row, no ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what I did is this:

```
new = data["info"].str.split("Email :|Address |WebSite :|City :|Pin Code :|State :|Contact No. :|GST No. :|Company Registration No. :|Contact Person :|Mobile No. :|Truck Available :|Services :|Service :", expand=True)
```

and then assign elements of new to data

```
data["Address"] = new[1]
data["Email"] = new[2]
data["Website"] = new[3]
data["City"] = new[4]
data["Pin Code"] = new[5]
```

Like this. and for multiple contact person I did this

```
data["Contact person 1"] = new[10]
data["p1_contact_no"] = new[11]
data["Contact person 2"] = new[12]
data["p2_contact_no"] = new[13]
data["Contact person 3"] = new[14]
data["p3_contact_no"] = new[15]
```

Comment: If anyone has a better/pythonic way to do this please tell me.